# Closed form solution for $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{p_k^{p_k+1}}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a closed form for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{p_k^{p_k+1}}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime? I know it converges, since it can be bounded by $\sum\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}$ and the best I could do so far was to bound it using the prime zeta function $P(3)$:

$$\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{5^6}+\ldots < \frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}+\ldots \; .$$

Moreover, it seems like it converges to the value $0.13740985247919013$.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why would there be a closed form? I highly highly highly highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite surprising if a closed form of this sum was known. Your sum is similar to one the sums in the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream), namely the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}.
$$
The sum obviously converges, but other than numerical approximations and the integral identity
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{-x} dx,
$$
not much is known concerning the value of this sum. Indeed, it is not even known whether this sum converges to a rational or irrational number. In light of the above identity, it may be possible to derive an integral formula (plus an error term) via the introduction of the von Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)$. Other than that, I doubt any "nice" formula for your sum exists.